# Where did `throw(...)` syntax come from?

Tags: c++, history

In our application we had a handful of (member, but that shouldn't matter) functions declared as

```
void SomeFunction(Type argument) throw (...);
```

With Microsoft Visual C++ that compiles just fine. But now I am trying to compile it with GCC and it rejects the `...` as syntax error. I remember hearing about this construct long ago, but looking at the specification neither C++03 nor C++11 seems to allow `...` there and I can't remember where I got it from. Does anybody know anything about origin of this (clearly pointless) construct?

Comment: I don't know why they support it, but presumably the syntax was chosen to mirror the `catch(...)` syntax; one means "can catch anything" and the other means "can throw anything"

Comment: I think we should all just blame the guys on the panel that were Java fans.

Comment: Why was this voted off-topic? How is this even _remotely_ off-topic?

Comment: Also note that C++11 deprecates the `throw` notation in function declarations.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Java came out after C++ already existed (though before it was fully standardized).

Comment: @NicolBolas Microsoft's `throw(...)` spec certainly didn't precede Java's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys(v=vs.80).aspx:

> "Visual C++ departs from the ANSI Standard in its implementation of
>   exception specifications."

Comment: I always jokingly called the gcc approach of following the specification to the letter "specification nazis" (especially when the specification excessively restrictive), but I really, really, really prefer it over the MSVC gratuitous extensions.